# How do we decompose an algebraic set $V(f)$ when $f$ is complicated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**how do we decompose the following algebraic sets :**

1. $V(x^3-2x^2y+2xy^2-y^3, x^4-x^3y-xy+y^2) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ and
2. $V(2x^3z+3x^2y^2+6y^3+4xyz+z^2) \subseteq F^2$ where $F$ is algebraically closed.

**into irreducible components?**

For ideals of the form $V(f)$ where $f$ is some simple polynomials, say, $f$ is in $F[x]$ or $f$ does not involve too many terms of high powers, I know how to decompose that kind of algebraic sets.

But if $f$ has the above form, how do I decompose $V(f)$? Is there a general method for this type of problem?

Comment: Same as you would for simple polynomials: you want to find a primary decomposition. There are algorithms for this in the characteristic zero noetherian case: see for example [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.12/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_primary_spdecomposition.html).